# Is this combination "which nor" correct?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, archaic-language, poetry

I found the following in [a poem by Matthew Prior (1664-1721)](https://archive.org/stream/poeticalworksma01johngoog#page/n166/mode/2up):

> In every act and turn of life he feels
>   Public calamities, or household ills :
>   The due reward to just desert refus'd :
>   The trust betray'd, the nuptial bed abus'd :
>   The judge corrupt, the long depending cause,
>   And doubtful issue of misconstrued laws,
>   The crafty turns of a dishonest state,
>   And violent will of the wrong-doing great:
>   The venom'd tongue injurious to his fame,
>   **Which nor can** wisdom shun, nor fair advice reclaim.

I wrote the following sentence:

> You have confidence **which nor can** even the Devil shake.

Does this mean "You have confidence which even the Devil cannot shake, either."?

I wrote this sentence; no citation.

Comment: It doesn't look grammatical to me.  I expect *not* instead of *nor* and *can* later: "You have confidence which **not** even the devil **can** shake."  What year was this written?

Comment: It's okay to ask about sentences you've written yourself, but please tell us you've done so.  When you post a sentence and ask "Does this mean…", most people think you're asking what someone *else's* sentence means.

Comment: That's fine, and I even upvoted the question after your edit, but without the additional information I would have voted to close because it looked like you were trying to interpret someone else's ungrammatical sentence without citing it.  Telling us you wrote it yourself is the difference between that upvote and that close vote.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an archaic/poetic usage, irrelevant to the needs of people learning current English.

Answer (score 3):

Archaic or poetic English used 'or ... or' or 'nor ... nor' in some sentences where modern English uses 'either ... or' or 'neither ... nor'. The first time I read 'or ... or' (in fact the only time I can remember reading it - for some reason it has stuck in my memory) is in Shakespeare's Henry V, when the king of England says:

> My learned lord, we pray you to proceed
>   And justly and religiously unfold
>   Why the law Salique that they have in France
>   *Or* should, *or* should not, bar us in our claim:

In modern prose, this would be something like: 'Tell me why French law would *either* allow me to claim to be king of France *or* prevent me from claiming to be'.

In Prior's poem, the meaning is something like: 'People keep saying things to him which neither their own wisdom nor other people's advice will tell them not to'. 
I suspect that the shorter form was used to save one syllable in the poetic metre.

I understood your own sentence, and it would possibly work in poetry or in the mouth of a character in a historical novel, but it's certainly not modern, standard English.

(Latin also has constructions like 'aut ... aut'. The most famous one is probably 'aut Caesar aut nihil' (either Caesar or nothing), meaning 'I'm one ambitious dude, get out of my way'.)

Answer (score 2):

*Which nor can wisdom shun, nor fair advice reclaim* is a poor example to follow, because it is [archaic](/questions/tagged/archaic), and because it is [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry).  I have never encountered anything like it.

Modern normal usage would be [***neither* something *nor* something else**](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor).  Think of it as a negated version of *or*, but which must also be introduced by the word *neither*.

Your attempted sentence

> You have confidence which nor can even the Devil shake.

is wrong, because *nor* requires at least two items (analogous to *or*, which requires at least two items).

Recommended corrections:

- You have confidence which even the Devil cannot shake.
- You have confidence which not even the Devil can shake.

Comment: It makes no sense to add _either_ at the end of the sentence.